# Anychart.Timeline: Zooming moves chart on containers with margin-left/margin-right != 0

Tags: javascript, anychart

If a margin-left or margin-right <> 0 is added to the chart container element (or a wrapping element) zooming using the mouse wheel or the zoom UI moves the chart to the left.

I forked a play ground example and added

```css
#container {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
```

to the original code.
Here is the link to the example: https://playground.anychart.com/tJlE0hGZ/1

Is there any chance to stop this behavior (other than removing the margins)?

---

**EDIT:** Upon reading the tips below I realized that I over-simplified my example.

What I really need is a chart container wrapped in a centered `<div/>`

HTML

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
html, body, #container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

I created a new playground fork:
https://playground.anychart.com/PD9ICirX/2

---

**UPDATE:** I reported this case to the AnyChart support team and after some days I received a mail stating that this behavior is in fact a bug which will be addressed in a future update.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be addressed in two ways.

**JS** *(recommended)*
Remove CSS rules corresponding to the margin of a container.
Call an [AnyChart margin method](https://api.anychart.com/anychart.core.SeparateChart#margin).

```
//set chart's margin
chart.margin(0, '10%')
```

[Example demo of the AnyChart margin method usage](https://playground.anychart.com/YrdOMukO)   *(line 44)*

**CSS**
Set container width to 80% with CSS rules.

```
#container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
```

[Example demo of the CSS rules](https://playground.anychart.com/nge36D42)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sadly none of the two solutions are applicable to my problem as I have to work within a centered page frame, i.e. there is a surrounding `<div style="margin-left: auto;margin-right:auto;">... <div class="container"></div>...</div>`. Do you have any hints for this situation as well?

Comment: Please update your initial question with an enriched code to reproduce the exact problem and a visual reference of your end goal so we can proceed with it.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question and added a new playground link that hopefully allows for a better understanding of my case.

Comment: @BergListe  
Unfortunately, we can not fully understand the issue. You can contact our support directly via email with the attached screen recording video. If we can resolve the issue successfully, we will update this StackOverflow answer accordingly.